# Perl DBI installation error "Can't open blib/li.pm" during make command

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm new to Perl and am trying to get DBI set up so I can get started with MySQL. I've run into a problem with DBI that arises during the make stage of the installation, and would very much appreciate some help with solving the issue. Many thanks.

Install information:

DBI v1.637, using Perl v5.18.2, on MacOS Sierra v10.12.6

Error information:

```
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Command -e 'mkpath' -- blib/lib/DBI
rm -f blib/lib/DBI/Changes.pm
cp Changes blib/lib/DBI/Changes.pm
cp Driver.xst blib/arch/auto/DBI/Driver.xst
cp lib/DBD/Sponge.pm blib/lib/DBD/Sponge.pm
cp dbi_sql.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbi_sql.h
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/classic.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/classic.pm
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoReturn.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoReturn.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm
cp DBI.pm blib/lib/DBI.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Base.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Base.pm
cp lib/DBD/File/Developers.pod blib/lib/DBD/File/Developers.pod
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ANSI.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ANSI.pm
cp lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/Developers.pod blib/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/Developers.pod
cp lib/DBI/W32ODBC.pm blib/lib/DBI/W32ODBC.pm
cp lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoType.pm blib/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoType.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Storable.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Storable.pm
cp dbixs_rev.pl blib/lib/dbixs_rev.pl
cp lib/DBI/Profile.pm blib/lib/DBI/Profile.pm
cp lib/DBI/PurePerl.pm blib/lib/DBI/PurePerl.pm
cp dbixs_rev.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbixs_rev.h
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/Base.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/Base.pm
cp lib/DBI/Util/CacheMemory.pm blib/lib/DBI/Util/CacheMemory.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProfileData.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileData.pm
cp lib/DBI/SQL/Nano.pm blib/lib/DBI/SQL/Nano.pm
cp lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/HowTo.pod blib/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/HowTo.pod
cp lib/DBI/ProxyServer.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProxyServer.pm
cp lib/DBD/NullP.pm blib/lib/DBD/NullP.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/null.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/null.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Response.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Response.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
cp Driver_xst.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h
cp lib/DBD/Gofer.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer.pm
cp lib/DBI/Util/_accessor.pm blib/lib/DBI/Util/_accessor.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm
cp lib/Win32/DBIODBC.pm blib/lib/Win32/DBIODBC.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/pedantic.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/pedantic.pm
cp DBIXS.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBIXS.h
cp lib/Bundle/DBI.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
cp dbd_xsh.h blib/arch/auto/DBI/dbd_xsh.h
cp lib/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Execute.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Execute.pm
cp lib/DBI/Gofer/Request.pm blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Request.pm
cp lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/corostream.pm blib/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/corostream.pm
cp lib/DBD/File.pm blib/lib/DBD/File.pm
cp lib/DBI/ProfileSubs.pm blib/lib/DBI/ProfileSubs.pm
cp lib/DBD/Proxy.pm blib/li
AutoSplit: Can't open blib/li.pm: No such file or directory
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 2
```

Comment: How are you installing it? Manually using the tarball or using cpan?

Comment: Try `$ perl -MCPAN -e shell` followed by `install DBI`.

Comment: Could you please post the generated `makefile`? You might have to use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or some such service.

Comment: Try installing any other version of this module as the lines:                         
cp lib/DBD/Proxy.pm blib/li
AutoSplit: Can't open blib/li.pm: No such file or directory
 This shows that the Proxy.pm is being copied as li but then the validation is done for li.pm as in the error. So this may be a packaging error in the tarball

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I've tried installing using tarball and cpan, both result in the same error, as does trying to install a previous version (v1.635)

Comment: @ikegami I tried using $sudo perl Makefile.PL and $sudo make and I have a slightly different error now: AutoSplit: Can't open blib/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer.pm: No such file or directory
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 2 . I put a pastebin of the makefile here: https://pastebin.com/mXaxUaYX

Comment: Can't look at this today. Remind me in 24 hours